# How to add vector fields in the block header?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, block-production, block

I want to add a vector fields in the block header of substrate chain. Is this possible?
If yes, How can i do that? Do we have any reference code for it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you can push something to the header's digest field.

Utilize `DigestItem::Other` that takes a `Vec<u8>` as input.

But I don't recommend puting a very large `Vec<u8>` into the header.

https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot-sdk/master/sp_runtime/generic/enum.DigestItem.html